# Way to Lock the only Single Field Value Under Custom Field(Azure DevOps)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, power-automate, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

[Field Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMEC6.png)I have created a new field under Azure DevOps Board named - Requirement and Test Case(s) Approved and their values were defined as Approved/Pending/Review.

Now as part of compliance I need to lock only the values Approved/Pending or restrict those values to changed only by the respective users (in specific groups) instead of locking the entire field name - Requirement and Test Case(s).

Tried Creating Dynamic Rules in ADO but there is no flexibility in ADO to lock only Particular Field Values
only able to lock the entire field to group.

Also tried using powerautomate to create flows and revert the field value if its changed by non-member of the group(but unable to fetch the group details of member in power automate ) , Also cannot find REST API to fetch the groups list of that particular member , So using that group list i can make condition in powerautomate as if current user(who updated the field value) is not equal to group (member) and changes the field value to Approved then revert back the field value to pending.

Comment: Why not use the Test Plans feature to manage your testing requirements?

Comment: Yes we are using test plans as main workitem to execute the tests, but for validating and to know the status we are creating set of custom fields in user story (also some of these custom fields are tied to power automate so once test cases are passed checklist will be auto set to done by power automate).